# org.json JSONObject.getString() behaving weirdly

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am using org.json for processing json data.
In this scenario I am passing this json string to the JSONObject.

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "firstName": "firstName"
}
```

As you see, here in this JSON 'id' is of type integer and 'firstName' is of type string.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
if (0!= Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("id"))) {
     //some business logic
}
```

Problem is here:
Even though id is of type integer in json, jObject.getString("id") was working perfectly in some machines. But in some other machines, jObject.getString("id") throws an exception like "id" not found..

I use Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

For me changing getString to getInt is a huge work to be done since I am using it this way in many places.. Why do you think I am getting this exception now suddenly?

Comment: *throws an exception like "id" not found..* are you sure all the machines you say are parsing the same json value?

Comment: Even though it is somtimes claimed to be different, computers behave deterministic. If your application runs different with the same input on different machines, I suggest you search for differences where they appear: In your runtime environment, not in your code.

Comment: @thst i agree with you

Comment: Why do you use such an old version of `org.json`? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20170516

Comment: use jObject.getInt("id"); it will work

Comment: and why u put 0!= .......       its not a good approach